# What is this theorem used in proving canonical correlation model?

Tags: matrix

I am watching a video about canonical correlation that proves the canonical correlation model.

In the prof's proof of the canonical correlation model, a theorem from matrix analysis is used. That is for any real symmetric matrix $B$, its eigenvalues $\lambda_1 \ge  \lambda_2 \ge ... \ge \lambda_p$ and their corresponding orthogonal eigenvectors $\bf{e}_1,\bf{e}_2,...,\bf{e}_p$, $\frac{{{\bf{xBx}}}}{{{{\bf{x}}^{\rm{T}}}{\bf{x}}}}$ achieves the maximum value when $\bf{x}=e_1$ and the this maximum value is $\lambda_1$.

The following is a screen capture.
[image]

I am wondering what this theorem is. Thank you.

Comment: There are several theorems in this statement: (1) real symmetric matrices have eigenvalues; (2) they are all real; (3) the eigenspaces are orthogonal; (4) $x^\prime Bx/x^\prime x$ is maximized with value $\lambda_1$ when $x=e_1$. Which one are you asking about?

Comment: @whuber Thank you for your reply. I am asking about (4).

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has been discussed (*en passant*) in several threads here, so I hope some reader will be able to point us to them.  In the meantime, it might help you to know that this is a simple, direct consequence of the [Spectral Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Finite-dimensional_case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spectral Theorem: $B = U\Lambda U^\top$, in which $\Lambda=\mathrm{diag}\,[\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n]$ and $U=[u_1,\dots,u_n]$, with $B\,u_i=\lambda_i u_i$, for $i=1,\dots,n$. Also, the matrix $U$ is orthogonal, which means that $U^\top U=UU^\top=I$, and, without loss of generality (check it out), we may suppose that the $\lambda_i$'s are in decreasing order.

Since $x^\top x=||x||^2$, maximization of $(x^\top Bx)/(x^\top x)=(x^\top/||x||) B(x/||x||)$ is equivalent to finding
$$
  \max_x\,\{x^\top B x : x^\top x=1\} = \max_x \,\{x^\top U\Lambda U^\top x : x^\top x=1\}. \qquad (*)
$$
If we define  $y=U^\top x$, then $(*)$ is equal to
$$
  \max_y\,\{y^\top \Lambda y : y^\top y=1\} = \max_y\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i y_i^2 : \sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2=1 \right\},
$$
which is maximized by $y$ such that its first coordinate is equal to $1$ and all other coordinates are equal to $0$. It follows immediately that the maximum is $\lambda_1$.